# remove common file between local branch and master and push to a new branch

Tags: git

I have master branch and Branch_A (which is local).

Let's say master has the following files:

```
master:
    -> File_1
    -> File_2
    -> File_3
```

And my local Branch_A has:

```
Branch_A:
    -> File_1
    -> File_2
    -> File_3
    -> File_4 (Added new)
    -> File_5 (Added new)
    -> File_6 (Added new)
```

I want my new branch (let's call it Delta) to have:

```
Delta:
    -> File_4 (Added new)
    -> File_5 (Added new)
    -> File_6 (Added new)
```

So far I just tried checking out the new branch out of Branch_A, then doing a diff with master, deleting everything, and then applying the patch:

```
git checkout Branch_A;
git checkout -b Delta;
git diff origin/master > mypatch.patch;
find . -type f -not -path '*/\.*' -exec rm -v {} \;
git apply mypatch.patch;
git status;
git add .;
git commit -m "Created delta branch Delta";
```

But I keep getting error with the apply command and I'm not sure this is even the correct approach here.

Comment: What error are you actually getting with the `git apply` command?

Answer (score 0):

**Follow the following steps:**

1. git diff master Branch1 > ../patchfile
2. git checkout Branch2
3. git apply ../patchfile
4. git add .
5. git commit -m "Created delta branch Delta"